# jQuery authoring and closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reading about writting [jQuery plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) an there is a section that talks about preserving dollar sign notation so that it doesn't collide with other libraries that use it.

It says:

> it's a best practice to pass jQuery to a self executing function
>   (closure) that maps it to the dollar sign so it can't be overwritten
>   by another library in the scope of its execution

And here is how they do it:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

  };
})( jQuery );
```

I'm trying to understand what they are saying and what this code is saying. How is the following code gets evaluated?

Does `function($){}` get executed and get `jQuery` object passed to it?

Does jQuery object become the $?

Answer (score 2):

Yes; `function($) { ... }` gets executed with the `jQuery` object passed to it. The `$` argument hides the `$` variable of the parent scope (if any) and gives it the value of the `jQuery` variable, but only for that block of code.

The reason you would want to do this is `$` may be used by a different library (say, [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)), but you still want to be able to use the `$` shorthand for `jQuery` within your plugin. By creating a function taking an argument of `$` and executing it with `jQuery` as that argument, you can use `$` rather than `jQuery` inside that function without overwriting the `$` outside of your function as used by Prototype.

Answer (score 2):

that can be written as:

```
function add_my_plugin_to_fn($) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
  }
}

add_my_plugin_to_fn(jQuery);
```

or

```
//window.jQuery = stuff; // in jquery initializer
function add_my_plugin_to_fn(any_object_with_fn_property) {
      any_object_with_fn_property.fn.myPlugin = function() {
      }
    }

    add_my_plugin_to_fn(jQuery);
```

all will add a function to jQuery's fn.myPlugin property. The only reason we use $ is because jQuery people like to use the single-letter '$' as a function name. it could just as easily be `jQuery.fn.myplugin` or `jq.fn.myplugin` or `_.fn.myplugin`.

This allows you to get out of situations where something like this happens

```
my_awesome_javascipt_.js
    function $(add_to_this) {
      return add_to_this + 1;
    }


jQuery.js

    window.jQuery = //all the jquery stuff
    //sees that window.$ already has a function in it and leaves it alone


my_jquery_plugin.js
  $.fn.myplugin; //this doesn't exist because $ is a function from the first file
  //you should have used jQuery.fn.myplugin. But that is a lot to type out. Doing the
```

immediately-invoking function trick forces a variable '$' that has a scope of the file.

And yes, the language really should do that for you. It is kind-of a stupid mechanism to be global-by-default. If you want somthing that fixes it, look at [coffeescript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) which helps you write javascript without a lot of the basic errors